# Why i'm getting error No overload for ... matches delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 i have a method DoRequest:

```
void DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands cmd)
        {
            progressBar1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    if (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum)
                    {
                        progressBar1.PerformStep();

                        _captureProcess.BringProcessWindowToFront();
                        // Initiate the screenshot of the CaptureInterface, the appropriate event handler within the target process will take care of the rest
                        _captureProcess.CaptureInterface.BeginGetScreenshot(new Rectangle(int.Parse(txtCaptureX.Text), int.Parse(txtCaptureY.Text), int.Parse(txtCaptureWidth.Text), int.Parse(txtCaptureHeight.Text)), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2), Callback,cmd);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        end = DateTime.Now;
                        txtDebugLog.Text = String.Format("Debug: {0}\r\n{1}", "Total Time: " + (end-start).ToString(), txtDebugLog.Text);
                    }
                })
            );
        }
```

Then i call this method in two places in form1 both in buttons click events:

```
DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Displayoverlays);
```

The error i get is in this method in form1:

```
void Callback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            using (Screenshot screenshot = _captureProcess.CaptureInterface.EndGetScreenshot(result))
            try
            {
                _captureProcess.CaptureInterface.DisplayInGameText("Screenshot captured...");
                if (screenshot != null && screenshot.CapturedBitmap != null)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                    {
                        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                        {
                            pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                        }
                        pictureBox1.Image = screenshot.CapturedBitmap.ToBitmap();
                    })
                    );
                }

                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoRequest));
                t.Start();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
```

The error is on : new ThreadStart(DoRequest)

Error   1   No overload for 'DoRequest' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart'

How can i solve the error ?

Comment: The compiler doesn't accept you naming a specific object type that you've defined yourself as the object you pass from the Thread.Start() method to the method that is the start of execution of the new thread. You can get the compiler to accept it by passing it through as "object", but that isn't very object-oriented.

Comment: Ah, forget what I wrote in the above comment, that is for Thread.Start(), not what you're using. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ThreadStart` constructor expects a delegate that returns void and takes no arguments. The error `Error 1 No overload for 'DoRequest' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart'` indictates that the method signature for `DoRequest` does not match the signature defined by a `ThreadStart` delegate. It'd be like you passing a string into a method that needed a double.

Consider using a [`ParameterizedThreadStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoRequest));
t.Start(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Displayoverlays);
```

And then edit your DoRequest method to expect an object that you can then cast:

```
void DoRequest(object data)
{
    // Get your command information from the input object.
    ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands cmd = (ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands)data;

    progressBar1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            if (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum)
            {
                progressBar1.PerformStep();

                _captureProcess.BringProcessWindowToFront();
                // Initiate the screenshot of the CaptureInterface, the appropriate event handler within the target process will take care of the rest
                _captureProcess.CaptureInterface.BeginGetScreenshot(new Rectangle(int.Parse(txtCaptureX.Text), int.Parse(txtCaptureY.Text), int.Parse(txtCaptureWidth.Text), int.Parse(txtCaptureHeight.Text)), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2), Callback,cmd);
            }
            else
            {
                end = DateTime.Now;
                txtDebugLog.Text = String.Format("Debug: {0}\r\n{1}", "Total Time: " + (end-start).ToString(), txtDebugLog.Text);
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Matt i'm getting error on the line: ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands cmd = data as ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands; on the right side on the: data as ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands; the error is: Error 1 The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('Capture.Interface.ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands' is a non-nullable value type)

Comment: Ah, its an enum so you have to cast it: `(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands)data`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a parameter in your `DoRequest`.

so you need `ParameterizedThreadStart`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/parameterizedthreadstart

and you need to set parameter type to `Object`

```
void DoRequest(object param)
{
YourType variable = (YourType)param;
// Something...
```

}